# backbone: better way to template?

Tags: backbone.js

I want to use the features of the IDE to build the templates therefore I avoid using inline templates. The other option is to have the templates in script tags but doing this causes Visual studio to stop giving intellisense for the template html.

I tried to store the template in a div tag and convert it into a script tag before the backbone templated it but for some reason it caused the attribute values (ex: href="{{test}}") to be encoded.

Is there a better way to build the template?

Comment: Honestly, I try to keep my templates so small that the IDE (or lack of) doesn't add much value.  I use CSS to style the template so the template just contains the elements that I need.  What type of support are you looking to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i put my templates in separate html files, and use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) to load them with its [!text](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#text) plugin. then there is also the added functionality of the !strip you can use with it

so technically instead of loading html from a script tag, you load if from a separate html file, and thanks to the !strip it does not load the  and  tags, but only the 's content.

more info on how to use could be seen here:
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text

Answer (score 2):

I use jQuery.get to load templates I store in html files.

http://encosia.com/using-external-templates-with-jquery-templates/

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery.get as above and then append what's returned to the body of the html document.  I'm told there are better ways to do it in a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186477/how-to-cache-jquery-template-in-backbone-view-via-ajax/8187233#comment10274024_8187233).